# Why don't we use "unsigned int" instead of "char" to implement a big integer class?

Tags: char, biginteger, unsigned-integer

I used to implement something acting as a very large integer using `char`. But it suddenly occurred to me that I can use `unsigned int`, which is more straight-forward to implement.

For example, I use every `unsigned int` to store at most 9 999 999, and make use of the most significant digit as a buffer to increment to the "next" `unsigned int`.

Thus, I can use 4 byte for 7 digits, instead of 4 digits while using `char`.

So, why do not we implement a big integer class with `unsigned int`?

Comment: How big do your integers have to be? You could get pretty big (9.22337204 × 10^18, I think?) with an unsigned 64-bit value without having to implement a whole new type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Who says you don't use uint for BigInteger? The C# BCL implementation of BigInteger (in System.Numerics) uses uint[] to store its bits.

In general, it will be more efficient to use the bits to represent a number, rather than the bits to represent the character digit of a number.